# How does Web Api side receive the uploaded file and some multipart/form-data parameters?

Tags: c#, upload, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to upload a flie(image) and four other string type parameters with one http request to my asp.net core web api application, and the Content-Type is multipart/form-data. I can receive one single flie(image) and save it, but after I added four string parameters, I don't konw how to receive and process them.

I tried to add [FromBody] attribute to my parameters, but it still don't work.

Here are some of my code:

```
[Route("addbook")]
public ActionResult AddBook([FromBody] string ownerid,string bookName,string bookAuthor,string bookIntro) 
{
IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files["bookcover"];
// process the file...

// the following code can't work!!!!
Book newBook = new Book {
                BookID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Name = bookName,
                Author = bookAuthor,
                OwnerID = ownerid,
                Introduce = bookIntro,
                UploadTime = DateTime.Now,
                BookCover = filename
            };
//save them to database...
}
```

I want to save the flie and read the string and save them to the database.

Thanks for help.
Frank.

Comment: Please provide your javascript code

Comment: Here are some of my js code, they are from wechat miniapp:        
wx.uploadFile({
      url: app.globalData.bookUrl+'addbook',
      header: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      filePath: this.data.bookCoverPath,
      name: 'bookcover',
      formData:{
        bookName: 'test',
        bookAuthor: 'test',
        ownerid: app.globalData.openid,
        bookIntro: 'test'
      },
      success(res) {//...} })

Comment: It's seems that I can receive the file and the other parameters when I don't use nginx proxy, but when  I used the nginx proxy , I would fail, the response statuscode is 502 bad gateway or 400 bad request. I can do other things with nginx proxy except upload flie. I don't know why. Am I lack of some configuration with the nginx ?